# $k$-dimensional variation on the infected squares puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, cellular-automata

The infected squares puzzle is a classic; you can read about it [here](http://20bits.com/article/the-infection-puzzle). I'm interested in the $k$-dimensional version, specifically in establishing an upper bound.

Consider an $n\times n\times\cdots n$ $k$-dimensional hypercube. Choose some integer $C$; let all cells whose coordinates sum to $C$ mod $n$ be "infected" cells. A cell becomes infected if it shares a hyperface (=codim 1) with $k$ infected cells. Will the whole hypercube become infected?

If so, the $k$-dimensional, codimension-1 neighborhood, threshold $k$ variation of the infected squares puzzle has an upper bound of $n^{k-1}$. (In fact, this is a lower bound as well, but I won't prove it here; it's the same strategy as in the original infected squares puzzle.)

Experiments with $k=2,3$ support this, though I'm having a hard time definitively proving that this works with $k=3$, and my visualization skills become strained in the $k=4$ case.

Comment: Fun fact: the $3\times3\times3$ case has 7 different optimal solutions (with 9 initially infected cells) up to symmetry, according to a computer search done by ZenoRogue

Comment: (Also, this is unrelated to the question at hand, but the threshold 3 2D case is fascinating. I believe the optimal solution for infecting the whole square is $\frac13n^2+\frac23n+c$, where $0\le c\le2$, and $c=0$ iff $n$ is one less than a power of two.)

Comment: This is proven in _Mathematical Mind Benders_, by Peter Winkler.

Comment: I spent $10$ years playing with the $k$-dimensional generalization of the infamous "Nine dots problem", so I have to pass... since, it could become more than addictive.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Ah, wonderful! I'll see if I can find an online copy of the relevant bit.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Found it! https://imgur.com/a/tCJ5p5W Wow, that's a nice argument (though I think there's at least one typo: it should be $x_i>x^*$ the first time and $x_i<x^*$ the second time). And they found the same configuration that I did!

Comment: The link you provide at the beginning of your question doesn't work (at least on my computer). Why that ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Dunno… Try Firefox?